# How to put a component in the background

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am trying to layer components over a background which itself is a component.

The background component is arranging some `svg` images

The background is implemented like this:

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import hexagonIcon from "@assets/enterprise/hexagon.svg";
import buildings from "@assets/enterprise/buildings.svg";
import { FC } from "react";

export const EnterpriseCoverBackground: FC = () => {
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <LeftHexagon src={hexagonIcon} />
      <RightHexagon src={hexagonIcon} />
      <Buildings src={buildings} />
    </Wrapper>
  );
};

const Buildings = styled.img`
  position: sticky;
  top: 100%;
  width: 100%;
`;

const LeftHexagon = styled.img`
  position: sticky;
  right: 100%;
  top: 30%;
  height: 50%;
`;

const RightHexagon = styled.img`
  position: sticky;
  top: 70%;
  left: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(180deg);
`;

const Wrapper = styled.div`
  background: linear-gradient(316.08deg, #2a1beb 3.44%, #0984f7 100%);
  overflow: clip;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: clip;
`;
```

Now in the parent I want to layer the page above the background and here is where I am encountering issues:

```
function MyPage(): React.ReactElement {
  return (
     <Container>
       <EnterpriseCoverBackground /> <<< I want this in the background
       ...the other children here ...
     </Container>
  );
}

const Container = styled.div`
  //display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
`;
```

I've tried to use zIndex on the background but in this case it overflowed outside the container it should be within:

```
// bad
<Container>
      <div
        style={{
          zIndex: -1,
          position: "absolute",
        }}
      >
        <EnterpriseCoverBackground />
      </div>
             ...the other children here ...
    </Container>
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, the Container styled div need to be in relative position, so his child can be in position absolute for him.

```
const Container = styled.div`
  //display: flex;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
`;
```

Than I think you can remove the div inside the Container component e change the Wrapper inside EnterpriseCoverBackground like this:

```
const Wrapper = styled.div`
  background: linear-gradient(316.08deg, #2a1beb 3.44%, #0984f7 100%);
  overflow: clip;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: clip;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
`;
```